# is it possible to calculate the sine of a number in a pine script study

Tags: pine-script

I want to know the angle of a line on a chart lets say joining the highs of each candle. Is it possible to calculate it knowing the distance between the tops of highs of 2 candles and the time unit of 1 between them, that would give the hypotenuse, thus all 3 sides of the triangle would be known, now is it possible to use sine function in Pine Script to get the angle of the line?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, figured it out, was kind of a silly question, when there is a SIN function built in, just had to find it, thanks  to all who looked at it.